# Gravar upload de arquivo no arquivo txt

Tags: php, html, formulário

Tenho esse código que grava as informações do formulário num arquivo `TXT.`
Porem não consigo enviar upload (uma imagem por exemplo).

Como posso fazer isso?

**Código:**

```
<?php

$file = 'apeople.txt';

// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);

// Append a new person to the file
$current .= $_POST ["top"]; $current .= "\n";
$current .= $_POST ["texto"]; $current .= "\n";
$current .= $_FILES ['arquivo']; $current .= "\n";
$current .= $_POST ["rodape"]; $current .= "\n";

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);

?>
```

Comment: O valor de `$_FILES ['arquivo']` não é o que você acha que é, faça um `var_dump` dele para ver o que tem dentro

Comment: Não entendi o quis dizer amigo, sou um pouco leigo em php.

Comment: E como você deseja armazenar uma imagem dentro de um arquivo TXT?

Comment: Dá uma lida na documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Não, quero que ela fique raiz ou numa pasta, mas que suas informações fique no arquivo, tipo assim: <img style="width: auto; height: auto;" alt="" src="img.jpg">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, me desculpe, mas é impossível você salvar uma imagem dentro de um .txt.
O que você pode fazer é salvar o nome da imagem dentro do txt e jogar a imagem em alguma pasta.

O nome do arquivo ficaria em

> $_FILES ['arquivo'][name]

No seu código ficaria assim:

```
$current .= $_FILES ['arquivo'][name];
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, deu certo.

Comment: Olá @F.Júnior ,vejo que você tem um total de 5 perguntas até o momento e apesar das repostas dadas a você terem ajudado você nunca aceitou uma resposta. Isso não é bom para a saúde do site, porque sua pergunta fica como não resolvida, ao aceitar uma resposta recompensara quem te ajudou e ajudara quem tiver p mesmo problema. =D   --   Vale apena você dar uma olhada no nosso [Tour]